# Converting Hibernate linq query to HQL

Tags: linq, nhibernate, hql

I understand that a IQueryable cannot be serialized. That means that queries can not be serialized, sent to a webservice, deserialized, queried and then sent back.

I was wondering if it is possible to convert a hibernate linq query to hql to be sent over the wire.

Is there another route I am missing?

Comment: I'm a little sceptic as to why you'd want to design your webservice to accept arbitrary queries in the first place. It is not generally a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've seen ADO.NET Data Services as advertised to work with NHibernate:

http://wildermuth.com/2008/07/20/Silverlight_2_NHibernate_LINQ_==_Sweet

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/21/ADO.Net-Data-Services-with-NHibernate.aspx

This is an old post, and not sure how maintained this feature is, but its worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion to you. Do not try to serialize query. Rather provide your user with an ability to compose arbitrary LINQ expression. Then send the expression over the wire (there is a gotcha here, since expressions are not serializable) to your server.

I have recently submitted to NHibernate.Linq project a change to their NHibernateExtensions class - a new ISession extension method List, which accepts an expression and fills the given list with the respective data, much like ICriteria.List method. The change was accepted (see [here](http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NHLQ-33)) so downloading the recent version of NHibernate.Linq should contain this method.

Anyway, you can find the details of this approach [here](http://www.shunra.com/shunrablog/index.php/2009/07/16/using-linq-expressions-in-a-client-server-application/).