# Does anyone know how to translate LINQ Expression to NHibernate HQL statement?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, hql, expression

Does anyone know of an existing solution to translate a LINQ Expression to HQL statement?

Thanks in advance to all the good samaritans out there.

P.S.

We already use Linq to NHibernate. However, it only works for select statements, whereas HQL is good for other statement kinds, like delete. So, Linq to NHibernate is not the answer.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192041/converting-hibernate-linq-query-to-hql

Comment: Not quite. I have also noticed that question and even answered it.

Answer (score 2):

Linq to nhibernate has just been [released](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/17/Implementing-Linq-for-NHibernate-A-How-To-Guide--Part.aspx) . Does that help?

Comment: I am using it already. It can only do selects, while HQL can be used in other operations, like delete. So no, it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same need: I needed to delete using a LINQ expression, but NHibernate only supports delete using HQL or SQL. I don't like this approach, since the rest of the code is completely strongly typed with LINQ expression, and I then had to relate to table and property names and manipulating strings.

I am working with NHibernate 3.0 and I came 95% of the way, but I had to use reflection to call some private/internal methods on the way. The below gives me an HqlQuery object for the LINQ expression:

```
NhQueryable<Product> queryable = (from p in session.Query<Product>()
                             where p.ProductId == 1
                             select p) as NhQueryable<Product>;
            if (queryable != null)
            {
                Expression expression = queryable.Expression;
                NhQueryProvider provider = queryable.Provider as NhQueryProvider;
                MethodInfo prepareQueryMethod = typeof(NhQueryProvider).GetMethod("PrepareQuery", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                object[] arguments = new object[] {expression, null, null};
                NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression = prepareQueryMethod.Invoke(provider, arguments) as NhLinqExpression;
                ExpressionToHqlTranslationResults translationResults = nhLinqExpression.ExpressionToHqlTranslationResults;
                HqlQuery hql = translationResults.Statement as HqlQuery;
            }
```

I am stuck on that I am not able to convert the HqlQuery object to a HQL string. Anyone have any input on this? Or did you solve your problem in a different way?

Anyway I think it could be a great addition to have an overload of ISession.Delete, that took an IQueryable or IQuery as parameter. I am a newbie to NHibernate, but it seems to me it should be a fairly simple task for someone knowing NHibernate to find some already existing methods and wire them up to do the job.

Comment: I took the liberty of reposting your findings on the dedicated NH mailing list. There is some traffic around this post - your action is required. The post URL is http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/07cff495aa5f12e1

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ for querying, HQL for delete and update. Even Criteria can still be useful sometimes instead of LINQ.

It's not an either/or situation, you can and should pick the best tool for each job.

Comment: HQL is NHibernate specific and as such is the server side DAL implementation detail. I do not want it to "leak" to the client side, which is the one requesting to delete some entities. So, the client specifies a linq expression. When the request is fetch - simple, because there is linq to nhibernate, which translate it to criteria and then selects by it. However, there is no delete statement by criteria and that is a problem.

Comment: That's another question altogether... please create another question to address that. When using multiple tiers IMO you shouldn't allow a client to send its own linq expression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330432/in-a-multitier-application-should-a-client-be-allowed-to-send-its-own-linq-expres